# Zsh not recognizing file changes with search path

Tags: macos, zsh

I'm using ZShell with Oh-My-Zsh on OS X 10.8.  Updates within my search path aren't immediately recognized.  My search path:

```
[~]$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

I had git in /usr/bin.  I used macports to install git, so after the port install the new executable is in /opt/local/bin.  But `git` command and `which git` still use the older one in /usr/bin.  If I open a new terminal window the new git in /opt is correctly used.

So how do you get zsh to recognize the updates to files in the path during the current shell session?  Is it running some other command that's cached and needs updating?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to rehash the known commands:

```
rehash
```

That's all!